# MySQL Copy From Cell A to Cell B IF Cell C has "Value"?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 
Field A, Field B, Field C and Field D.

I would like to run a query that says IF "Field C" has the word "dog" then "Field A" will be copied to "Field B".

I can get "Field A" to copy over to "Field B" but I need it only to copy when "Field C" has the word "dog".

Hope the above makes sense.  I'm using phpMyAdmin and have a "general" understanding of what I'm doing, by I'm not an expert in any way!

Thanks for reading and your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET fieldb = fielda
WHERE fieldc LIKE '%dog%'
```

that litteraly means: if inside field c you find the word dog (i.e. "the dog is in the house") then set the value of fieldb to be equal to that of field a

If you are looking for an exact match of the field c you can just use:

```
UPDATE table
SET fieldb = fielda
WHERE fieldc = 'dog'
```

that will look if the field c contains exactly only the word dog

Answer (score 0):

If `has` means "exactly" then:

```
UPDATE mytable SET fieldb = fielda WHERE fieldc = 'dog';
```

If `has` means "contains" then:

```
UPDATE mytable SET fieldb = fielda WHERE fieldc LIKE '%dog%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add

`WHERE fieldc like '%dog%'`

or

You can use `case`

```
UPDATE someTable
SET fieldb = CASE WHEN fieldc LIKE '%dog%' THEN fielda ELSE fieldb END
```